# Portrait image is rotated 90 degrees from expected when displayed. NaturalHeight andNaturalWidth are reverse of what is expected

Tags: javascript, css, image, react-redux, orientation

I have a React app that displays a series of images. Recently I've begun to notice that some images which are snapped as portrait are displaying on UI as rotated by 90 degrees. I've eliminate all of the css stylings in an effort to figure out why this is happening, however removing all of them hasn't changed the orientation at all.

This has led me to conclude that its the browser (Chrome) that is making the determination of orientation. One thing noticed is that browser shows the NaturalHeight and NaturalWidth values for the rotated images as reversed from what is expected. For example, if a certain image is viewed using Gimp the exif ImageLength x ImageWidth shows as 3088x2320 which is correct for a portrait image. However - interrogating the same image in the app via the browser reports NaturalHeight x NaturalWidth as 2320x3088, which is reversed.

So questions are:
1) why the reversal? and
2) is there anything that can be done about this?

Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem with photo taken with smartphone, In the exif data you can read the orientation, but browser ignore this data. I have resolved using a plug in to read orientation and rotate image.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani thanks for the feedback. If you don't mind, what is the name of the plugin you are using?

Comment: We work with .net platform and in our platform we have integrated this https://imageresizing.net/ for resize and other things like rotate. But i know there are something in jquery to do this.